# Using Papertrail with tattletale.js on Heroku

Tags: javascript, angularjs, heroku, papertrail-app

I have a simple client-side AngularJS application that I'm running on Heroku. I want to log input on Papertrail and saw this simple example using [Tattletale.js](https://github.com/vimeo/tattletale.js):

```
var tattletale = new Tattletale('https://probat-arabica-29.herokuapp.com/log');
tattletale.log('“My name is Ozymandias, king of kings:');
tattletale.log('Look on my works, ye Mighty, and despair!”');
tattletale.log(42);
tattletale.send();
```

My question is where the `/log` endpoint comes from on that example? Is the expectation that you need the server-side code to provide that? I've searched through the Heroku/Papertrail config pages to no avail. Any help?

Comment: I just read the docs. I didn't really understand it either